# PHP statement switch case etiquette

Tags: php, switch-statement

**1**

```
switch($app_id){
    case (
        $app_id == 1 || 
        $app_id == 2
    ):
        //do something
    break;
    case 3:
        //do something else
    break;
}
```

and

**2**

```
switch($app_id){
    case 1:
    case 2: 
        //do something
    break;
    case 3:
        //do something else
    break;
}
```

apart from etiquette, is there a better reason why you wouldn't do the second or is it entirely up to you?

Reason i ask is because in php.net it says that you should not do the latter regardless of if you want to **(snippet from php.net saying you shouldn't do cases without breaks regardless of if you want to stack up the queries or not)**:

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
case 0:
    echo "i equals 0";
case 1:
    echo "i equals 1";
case 2:
    echo "i equals 2";
}
?>
```

Here, if $i is equal to 0, PHP would execute all of the echo statements! If $i is equal to 1, PHP would execute the last two echo statements. You would get the expected behavior ('i equals 2' would be displayed) only if $i is equal to 2. Thus, it is important not to forget break statements (**even though you may want to avoid supplying them on purpose under certain circumstances**).

**Reasons so far:**

1. *ANSWER:* if I omit a break to allow for a fall-through, I put in a
   comment to say that there's a fall-through occuring, just so the
   next person coming along doesn't go "aha! missing break! BOOM" –
   Marc B

   *MY COMMENT:* Excellent reason Marc! that is the bum of etiquette.. if
   you break it, people aren't ready to be pood on by their captain
   correctness.
2. *ANSWER:* @JamesT: What you've read only warns you about forgetting it
   by mistake, because it's a very common programming error. You can do
   it if it's intended. – Madara Uchiha

   *MY COMMENT:* I think then that etiquette wins this question. Do put
   breaks in because it may be confusing to the next person editing
   your code; alas do it if you are sensible enough to put in a comment
   to explain you meant to miss it out
3. *ANSWER:* You're miss understanding their sentiment. They're talking about omitting breaks when there are individual actions for each case, such as my first example. Grouping cases, such as my 4 and 5 from example one is perfectly fine and encouraged if actions are entirely shared across cases. – Rawkode

   *MY COMMENT:* I agree that this sentence can be misread. I see no reason apart from confusing future developers into questioning whether you did or did not mean to leave a break out.

Comment: I don't think you're placing your `break` statement(s) correctly.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't be using `switch` at all.

Comment: Sorry please reread question, i sodded my question up. sorry. ive corrected it.

Comment: if I omit a break to allow for a fall-through, I put in a comment to say that there's a fall-through occuring, just so the next person coming along doesn't go "aha! missing break! *BOOM*"

Comment: That's a very interesting reason! THANKS! keep em coming!

Comment: @MarcB, `BOOM` made me laugh too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your first example is likely not to behave the way you expect it.

```
switch($app_id){
    case (
        $app_id == 1 || 
        $app_id == 3
    ):
        //do something
    case 3:
        //do something else
    break;
}
```

This would evaluate the condition and resolve to a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value, which would then be compare to `$app_id`. In this (very specific) case, you'll get the expected result, **but this isn't the correct way of doing it!**.

When using a switch case, the second approach you've displayed is better.

---

The break statement is used to exit from a case once it is satisfied. You can leave it out, and execute all subsequent cases. **It's perfectly fine implement it that way if that's the expected behavior.** Don't forget to add comments to clarify it. Be kind to future you!

Comment: Please check the question again, I mistyped it and have corrected it. I know how statements work, I am wondering why php.net doesn't want you to leave out breaks regardless of if itll work or not.

Comment: I wonder why php.net states you shouldn't do it then? Odd for them to put it then and then follow with demonstrations of its use. Maybe im misreading the statement

Comment: @JamesT: What you've read only warns you about forgetting it by mistake, because it's a very common programming error. You can do it if it's intended.

Answer (score 0):

The switch below is the same as `if($i == 1 || $i == 2 || $i == 3)`

```
switch($i) {
  case 1:
    echo "1";
  case 2:
    echo "2";
  case 3:
    echo "3";
    break;
}
```

Assuming $i == 1, the above code would actually output "123" - which is typically incorrect.

Correct example:

```
if ($i == 1) // Do something
else if ($i == 2) // Do something else, etc
```

is the same as

```
switch(i) {
  case 1:
    echo "1";
    break;
  case 2:
    echo "1";
    break;

  case 4:
  case 5:
    echo "This is 4 and 5";
    break;
}
```

The above code is only going to output "1" for $i == 1

Some people do contain their cases within {}'s, but this is purely for readability and will not force a break.

In regard to your example of `case (4 || 5)` - This will cause a syntax error.

Comment: The question is.. why do you do one over the other. regardless of the exact same outcome. Is it just etiquette to do conditions like statement 1

Comment: Updated answer with a couple more points. Example two, I would say, it the preferred example. It's clean and easy to ready/follow.

Comment: but php.net states that you should not miss out breaks.. so the question is why. from your statement, if i == 3, then itll output "1 This is 4 and 5".. if you want that to happen, why shouldnt you do it like that... I think the answer is.. etiquette.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php. Search for "Here, if $i is equal to 0"

Comment: You're miss understanding their sentiment. They're talking about omitting breaks when there are individual actions for each case, such as my first example. Grouping cases, such as my 4 and 5 from example two is perfectly fine and encouraged if actions are entirely shared across cases.